# EE 3.5.15 - Control Panel Expires

Tags: control-panel

I am running EE 3.5.15 and the Control Panel continually times out, even when I am active in the system.

I added the following to config.php but it has not made any difference:

$config['cp_session_ttl'] = 86400;
$config['user_session_ttl'] = 86400;

It may go 30 minutes more or less when it will suddenly time out and I have to log in again to continue - usually losing an entry in the process.

Any hope for a solution?

Comment: Is this website running in your local server or live server?

Comment: It is running on a live server.

Comment: Only possible solution I see here is to change session type. Go to `settings > Security & Privacy` and change `CP session type` to `Cookies Only.`

Comment: Hi Mufi. I'll give that a try today and let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Alas, it still closes out after about 30 minutes!

Comment: Can you setup your website to local server ? If yes then check this issue will be still present or not. If issue will be not in your local server then we can decide that your code of website have no problem but problem in your live server.